# Set a renderer for a column with a click of a button

Tags: extjs

I want to create a button that when I click on it, it will set a `renderer` for a `column` on my grid. I'm looking through the API for columns http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column

and I do not see a method that says `setRenderer`, how can I achieve this?

Edit: I do not want to set it when I create the column ( i know there is a property to set the renderer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try simply changing the renderer, no need for a setRenderer

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', 
         renderer: function (value) {
             return value + ' Simpson';
         }},
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    bbar: [{
        text: 'Change First Column Renderer',
        handler: function(b) {
            var grid = b.up('grid'),
                columns = grid.getColumnManager().getColumns(),
                column = columns[0];

            column.renderer = function(value) {
                return value === 'Lisa' ? 'L Simpson' : value;
            }
            grid.view.refreshView();
        }
    }]
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a5e

Comment: Agree! I did this a lot in my last project and it's working like a charm.